# Java - Unknown column in 'field list' jdbc error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I've got this error from my jdbc driver. I don't know why, tho.

Here's the corresponding code:

```
try {
    String colNames = " ";
    for (int i=0; i<cols.size(); i++) {
        if (i == cols.size()-1) {
            colNames += cols.get(i);
        } else if (i<cols.size()) {
            colNames += cols.get(i)+", ";
        }               
    }       
    String colValues = " ";
    for (int i=0; i<values.size(); i++) {
        if (i == values.size()-1) {
            colValues += values.get(i);
        } else if (i<values.size()) {
            colValues += values.get(i) + ", ";
        }       
    }
    System.out.println(
        "INSERT INTO `" + tableName + "` (" + colNames + ") VALUES (" + colValues + ") "
    );
    //System.out.println(kerdojel);

    PreparedStatement pst = connHandler.conn.prepareStatement
        ("INSERT INTO `" + tableName + "` (" + colNames + ") VALUES (" + colValues + ") ");
    pst.executeUpdate();
    pst.close();
}
```

"values" and "cols" are ArrayLists that contains the data from the JTable.
cols are the Column names and values are the cell values.

The output for the Sysout:

```
INSERT INTO `TableOne` ( nev, kor, lakhely) VALUES ( asd, 1, asd)
```

The error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'asd' in 'field list'
```

Comment: use single inverted commas for values. On a side note use `setString()` etc methods to set the values

Comment: Thanks, but still, I got the error.

Comment: show the output of query and the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how the `PreaparedStatement` was intended to be used. When you use a `PreparedStatement`, you can specify the values by using one of the "set" methods.

Here is an example:

```
String colNames = " ";
String colValues = " ";
for (int i=0; i<cols.size(); i++) {
    if(i!=0){
       colNames += ", ";
       colValues += ", ";
    }
    colNames += cols.get(i);
    colValues += "?";              
}       

try (PreparedStatement pst = connHandler.conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `" + tableName + "` (" + colNames + ") VALUES (" + colValues + ") ");){

    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        pst.setString(i+1,values.get(i));       
    }

    pst.executeUpdate();
}
```

You should use the appropriate "set" method based on the column's data type (`setInt(...)`, `setDate(...)`, etc.). You can find more details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString(int,%20java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

Try to use command like these one to check problem existed.

```sql
PREPARE mycmd FROM 'INSERT INTO TableOne(nev,kor) VALUES (?, ?)'
```